# tiny_mce_before_init: 'exact' => true has no effect

Tags: theme-development, filters, tinymce

For a custom theme, the editors want to be able to select three different font sizes in the post editor.

I thought about using a standard font size plus defining two extra classes:

```
<p class="bigger">
```

and

```
<p class="smaller">
```

Therefore I define the following formats in `tiny_mce_before_init`:

```
$style_formats = array(
    array(
        'title'    => 'bigger paragraph',
        'block' => 'p',
        'exact'    => true,
        'classes'  => 'bigger',
    ),
    array(
        'title'    => 'smaller paragraph',
        'block' => 'p',
        'exact'    => true,
        'classes'  => 'smaller',
    ),
);
```

The formats do get displayed in the formats dropdown box and do work.

Unfortunately, they can be selected together, which results in Markup like this:

```
<p class="bigger smaller">
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You aren't going wrong. The author is telling the editor he wants the text to be both smaller and bigger. So that's what he gets.

Comment: The way I understand the docs, 'exact'=>true means that only one of the classes can be applied: "Disables the merge similar styles feature when used. This is needed for some CSS inheritance issues such as text-decoration for underline/strikethough."  [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working exactly as it should.  The `style_formats` filter allows you to add additional styles via class names.  It is perfectly valid for an element to have multiple classes (and is not limited to only two).

I've been working with the tinymce editor for years; and I can honestly say I have no idea what the "exact" argument does, exactly.  I have never had a situation where it made a difference.  BUT, I can say with certainty it does NOT limit an html element to only have one class.

If what you are trying to achieve is a way for a user to enlarge/reduce the font size; then you should re-consider your approach.  I would make two new editor buttons (perhaps up and down arrows); and write the code to enlarge or reduce the font-size of the element.

Alternatively, you could create three new editor buttons (one for each font size), that when clicked, removes any existing font-size class on the element, and adds the new one.

In summary, I do not believe your current approach will limit an element to a single class name.  I would consider a new approach.  There are plenty of articles out there detailing how to add a new editor button.

Comment: I had the same impression about the "exact" argument ;-) Will create extra editor buttons now. Thank you very much, Josh!!!